# Azure Functions- Publish local.settings.json

Tags: azure, azure-functions

How Can I publish my Azure Function's local.settings.json?

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "CosmoDbAuthKey": "***********************************",
    "CosmoDbEndpoint": "https://**************************:443/",
    "CosmosDbId": "***Notifications"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not condoning the practice of publishing the `local.settings.json` file, since it is intended to be used for local development and debugging only.  Others have already emphasized that, but they are apparently mistaken that there is "no way to publish".  There is indeed a method to publish it and it's specified in [Microsoft's online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local?tabs=windows%2Ccsharp%2Cbash#local-settings-file):

> By default, these settings are not migrated automatically when the project is published to Azure. Use the --publish-local-settings switch when you publish to make sure these settings are added to the function app in Azure. Note that values in ConnectionStrings are never published.

Comment: Also, it seems that most restrictions are due to Visual Studio tools and/or other automated tools.  Using Azure DevOps Pipelines, it seems that about any and all files can be deployed in your cloud solutions.  In fact, if you're not careful using alternative deployment (i.e. publication) methods, the `local.settings.json` and other development-only files could be inadvertently deployed.  It takes significant and purposeful configuration of project settings and deployment settings and techniques to ensure it's all correct... more than can be documented here.

Answer (score 0):

You **can** publish your `local.settings.json` file to the Application Settings blade of your Azure Function. Use [Azure Function Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-core-tools-reference?tabs=v2#func-azure-functionapp-publish) with the `--publish-local-settings` flag.

It can be challenging to keep track of local vs. DEV vs. PROD settings in this manner, but it is possible.

Ensure you use [KeyVault References](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli) in the file, otherwise you will likely push secrets to your github repo, etc.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot publish local.settings.json, what you need to do is to add them under the "Application settings" tab of the published function app in the [**`Azure Portal`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-develop-vs#function-app-settings)

[image]

Comment: Action tab not showing for me. I am using visual studio 2019 Enterprise edition.

Comment: Check it in the portal itself

Comment: @Sajeetharan - I have published local.settings.json by adding it in source control and I have verified from the portal that Function App is reading its configuration values from this file. I was just curious to understand which source (i.e. local.settings.json or something else) Function App uses to set its environment variables?

Comment: Refer this thread https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1594