# Unable to publish local .settings contents in Azure function

Tags: azure-functions

I am trying to build and publish my Azure function and it shows to be published succesfully in Visual Studio. However, when I go to Azure portal, i dont see the Connection strings and other settings from my local.settings.json file being published there? What is happening. On doing a Build of my function app, its build successfully with a warning that

> Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: Access to the path
> 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ExtensionsMetadataGenerator.dll' is
> denied.

I fear i have done something wrong. yesterday I did "clear all Nuget cache " and that might be causing this issue. Any idea how do i fix it?

Comment: the name should say it all: local.settings.json is only for your LOCAL debugging. It is not to be uploaded to Azure (or any other compute target)

Comment: you need to set your app settings explicitly when publishing your Function. Many of the settings might (usually) be different from what you are using locally. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings

Comment: when we do a publish from Visual Studio. the local settings gets copied to Azure function in portal. I have done it before and it does happen

Comment: when you start creating a function app in VS. you have some default files generated for Azure function like host.json and localsettings.json

Comment: yes, those files get generated for you, but the local.settings.json still doent belong into the deploy target. and yes, you can in VS chose to copy certain settings, but you need to do so. It does not happen automatically since that would not be desirable since, again, usually you use different settings in the cloud

Comment: figured out it seems I needed to set up Azure App settings and copy local and remote values and then publish, you can post as answer

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66166144/2854993

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed: You need to manually populate the App Settings on the Function in Azure. local.settings.json are not uploaded - and are not intended to.

Visual Studio provides you some help copying values over, but you need to initiate that - as often you would use different settings in the cloud than for local debugging.