# Deploying Azure Function with Jetbrains Rider and Azure Toolkit with local settings

Tags: c#, azure, deployment, azure-functions, rider

I am using Jetbrains Rider on my Mac to develop some Azure Functions (.NET 6/C#). I use  Azure Toolkit to deploy them to Azure (CI/CD processes would be over-engineered in this cases). The basic deployment works perfectly fine to me.

However, in Visual Studio Professional/Enterprise on my company's laptop (using Windows) I have the option to deploy Azure Functions with a selected sub-set of local settings.

For anybody who is interested in this option, it is described here (screenshots are not up-to-date with VS 2022, but you will find it): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/513945/how-can-i-make-azure-functions-use-settings-in-loc

Is there any build in option in Jetbrains Rider? Or do I have to use Azure CLI?

[image]

Comment: could use plugin - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/11220-azure-toolkit-for-rider

Answer (score 5):

> By default local.settings.json is not deployed in Azure Functions as it is used for local development and also its part of gitignore file where it is not included during runtime, Refer this [**SO thread answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62669606/azure-functions-publish-local-settings-json) by Chris B and below:-

**gitignorefile:-**

[image]

***While Publishing Azure Functions with Jet-Brains Rider unfortunately, There's no option to Edit and configure App settings while Publishing as we have in Visual Studio code, But you can add it with Azure tool kit > Azure Explorer and Function app Refer below:-***

I created one Azure Function app in my JetBrains IDE  and Published it in my Azure Function app like below:-

[image]

Added HTTP Trigger in the Function like below:-

[image]

[image]

I ran the Function locally and it triggered successfully:-

[image]

**While Publishing this Function to function app in Azure there's no option to edit app settings,** Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

**I clicked on Run and the Function was Deployed in function App successfully,** Refer below:-

[image]

**You can add the appsettings in your Function app before publishing your Trigger or after Publishing your Trigger as App settings is Function app level settings applied to all triggers inside it by following the steps below:-**

***Go to Azure Explorer in your JetBrains rider > Select your Function App > right click > Show Properties like below:-***

[image]

***Function app publish profile and app settings page will load > click on Add `'+'` Button on right section of app settings and add your settings like below:-***

[image]

**Click on Save like below to save your app settings:-**

[image]

**App settings added successfully in Function app refer below:-**

[image]

**App settings reflected in Portal:-**

[image]

You're right, As a workaround you can directly add the Function App settings via Azure CLI like below:-

**Command:-**

I have referred the below command from this [**MS Document**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-appsettings-set).

```bash
az functionapp config appsettings set --name siliconfunc45 --resource-group siliconrg1 --settings 'SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_CONFIGURATION = true'
```

[image]

[image]

**Portal:-**

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks for all that effort, @SiddheshDesai. I gave it a +1. For me it is over-engineered, but I am sure it will be helpful for anyone who searches for it.

Comment: As I had already a solution for parsing local.settings.json for unit tests, I used this parser to output the settings the way, they are stored in the azure portal and just copy+pasted them. This made a quick manual process possible.